# How do I install CouchDB 1.1.0?

Tags: 11.10, installation, couchdb, source

I'm trying to get CouchDB 1.1.0 going on my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop. So far I was unable to find a binary package and even so all dependencies and dev headers are installed, I'm unable to compile it.

The configuration ends with this error message.

```
...
checking for JS_NewContext in -lmozjs... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs3250... no
checking for JS_NewContext in -ljs32... no
configure: error: Could not find the js library.

Is the Mozilla SpiderMonkey library installed?
```

I was however able to install the source on a Debian 6.0.3 box without issues. I think it has something to do with the different SpiderMonkey packages between those two platforms.

The current trunk checked out from github compiled fine, yet I'd like to use the latest stable version (1.1.0) rather than the development version.

Any thoughts on what I might do wrong? Is there perhaps a binary package ready for installation somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just missed CouchDB 1.1.1
The problem was buried within an incompatibility with SpiderMonkey 1.8.5. The release notes make that clear. The new version compiles just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to install the latest couch on any environment: https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:randall-leeds/couchdb
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Install spidermonkey, choose install from source :

- https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_SpiderMonkey

continue with the installation :

- https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu

---

**Easiest**: using [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb)

Build CouchDB is a wrapper or master project which pulls in, from official sources, CouchDB plus all of its dependencies. It is the most straightforward and reliable procedure to build official CouchDB releases from source.

P.S there is a error on ubuntu package ....

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5 rake
```

Comment: On 11.10 it seems to be called "libmozjs185-dev". Its installed, yet doesnt't work.

Comment: hm, nice script. I'll add it to my "cool" couchDB linklist. Thanks :)